# NFC simultaneous communication with multiple tags

Tags: tags, nfc

I'm interested in the possibility of a communications protocol that allows an NFC transceiver to communicate with more than one tag at the same time, or, at very least, to be able to choose to communicate with a specific tag while there are multiple within its range.  Unfortunately, I am new to the existing protocols for NFC communication so I do not know weather such a protocol exists or if it is even theoretically possible.

I believe that there was a thread asking about this in the context of Android 3 and it was determined that this sort of thing was impossible at the time.  That was nearly two years ago now and I suspect that the situation has improved.

Comment: I suspect not. What is the real application for this feature?

Comment: @Thomas I have multiple modules that are equipped with nfc chips/antennas that will be an average of of 12mm apart, on parallel planes.  I'd like to be able to connect to an individual module without interference from the others nearby.  I'm sorry, but I can't give any of the specifics of the project. My real interest and concern is whether or not something like this would even be possible.

Comment: Uhm this sounds problematic, at least for simultaneous communication; there will be additional noise for closeby nodes. You need to check out the NFC communication protocol to determine if your functionality is supported. And if so, whether that is implemented / can be controlled in your devices.